# Socket.IO Server in Google Cloud Run doesn't work

Tags: sockets, ionic-framework, websocket, google-cloud-run

I'am working on a Chat app, (I use Ionic React as frontend and Node as Backend).
My backend uses Express.js and frontend comunicates with my server with Socket.IO.

In my local environment everything works great.

Anyway after having deployed my server to Google Cloud Run It seems Socket.IO doesn't work anymore: emitting any socket.io event from my frontend doesn't lead to any response from my server.

My server code is the following:

```js
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8100"
  }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Socket connected")
  ..... //my code
}
```

But nothing works...

In my Google Cloud RUn console I got this:

[image]

By inspecting one of the log line I have:

[image]

As you can see, there are no errors in my logs, so I don't understand where I'm going wrong...

Comment: Open the Chrome browser "Inspect" debugger. Do you see any errors or warnings?